# Numerical derivative of function wrt natural log of variable

Tags: python, logging, space, numerical, derivative

The function that I am trying to evaluate is

```
d y / d ln(x)
```

where d is the derivative. However I have a set of data points for x and y with uncertainties. Now I think that this derivative can be evaluated by finding the slope of the data in log space however I'm not sure if that's the correct translation of this analytic formula to a discrete formulation.

The weighted least squares function below is correct and I want to know does the evaluation of the formula above correspond to the value of the slope, A, in the code? If not, how would I evaluate it?

```
import numpy as np

x = 0.5*np.array([
2900 + 3700,3700 + 3950,3950 + 4113,4113 + 4250,
4250 + 4400,4400 + 4500,4500 + 4600,4600 + 4700,
4700 + 4800,4800 + 4900,4900 + 5000,5000 + 5100,
5100 + 5200,5200 + 5300 ])

y = np.array([
0.14429,0.14408,0.14467,0.14500,
0.14653,0.14491,0.14396,0.14376,
0.14447,0.14461,0.14381,0.14301,
0.14361,0.14541])


yerr = np.array([
   0.00230,   0.00143,   0.00089,   0.00088,
   0.00087,   0.00093,   0.00085,   0.00073,
   0.00086,   0.00076,   0.00081,   0.00081,
   0.00089,   0.00077])


def wleastsq(x,y,w):
    # weighted least squares
    # y = Ax + B
    d = sum(w)*sum(w*x*x) - sum(x*w)**2
    B = (sum(w*x*x)*sum(w*y) - sum(w*x)*sum(w*x*y))/d
    A = (sum(w)*sum(w*x*y) - sum(w*x)*sum(w*y))/d
    # uncertainties
    sigA = np.sqrt( sum(w*x*x)/d )
    sigB = np.sqrt( sum(w)/d )
    return A,B,[sigA,sigB]

A,B,sig = wleastsq( np.log(x),y,1./yerr )
```

Comment: Instead of programming it yourself, risking all kinds of errors, you should look into `numpy` or `scipy` curve fitting tools. Also, your question ultimately is a mathematical one; checking your math is not Python-related.

Comment: I've already independently verified the fitting algorithm, I'll just go to the math stack exchange then.